# JSON Result not correct MVC

Tags: json, model-view-controller, get

I created an application where i can create invoices. So if i'm selecting my articles for my invoice not all values are taken by my JSON Result. 
The article select looks like this

[image]
My Code in the View looks like this

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "/Rechnung/GetArtikel",
     datatype: "Json",
     success: function (data) {
          $.each(data, function (index, value) {
              $('#Artikel').append('<option value="' + value.Id + '">' + value.Artikel, + value.Menge, + value.Preis '</option>'); //+ value.Einzelpreis + value.Menge
          });
     }
});
```

And in my Controller

```
 return Json(db.Artikel.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

So where am I wrong? I'm a beginner in JSON
Thanks for your help

Comment: can you post your JSON data

Comment: if you have a problem with your data, it would be sensible to show your data! Do you know how to use the Developer Tools in your browser to look at what the AJAX call is returning?

Comment: No sorry can you explane to me where i can find this data?

Comment: Press F12 in most browsers to open the tools. Go to the "Network" tab. Now, run your ajax request...you should see a line in the Network tab showing a request to the "GetArtikel" URL. Click on it, and you'll see more tabs showing the request going out, and the response coming back. Assuming the request succeeded, you'll see your JSON data in the "Response" section. If the request failed (e.g. the Response was not 200 OK) you might see an error message instead, and you'll also see a different (non-200) status code. There might also be a message in the Console section of the tools.

Comment: P.S. most browsers, e.g. Chrome, Firefox in particular, have lots of documentation and examples online showing you how to use these tools, if you care to look for yourself. If you're going to start working with AJAX, you need to learn to use the tools to help you debug. In fact if you're going to do any work with JavaScript in general, you'll need them. They're like your IDE (equivalent to Visual Studio for .NET) - there's a console, a debugger, an inspector, and all kinds of monitoring tools.

Comment: ADyson this is my dropdown box in my html view                                                     'Html.Label("Artikel", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label " })'
' Html.DropDownList("Artikel", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text")...                $('#BtnAdd').on('click', function () {

var artikelId = $('#Artikel').val();
var artikel = $("#Artikel option:selected").text();
var beschreibung = $("#Beschreibung").val();
....

                        var model = {
                            ArtikelId: artikelId,
                            Artikel: artikel,.....